# getting 405 http error when reading form data in asp.net core web api controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Since I am new to webapi my project fornt-end is react js and backend is Asp.net core 3.1 webapi
so i am redirecting to page given below  with query string format username|redirecturl

```
username:Identify user
redirecturl:controller url where i will receive posted form data

--Request Url----
https://example.com/anonymouspage.aspx?req=username|https://localhost:5001/api/ControllerName/PostTodoItem
```

above page will redirect back to controller url which i have share in query string with following given response

```
---Response---
<form name='ecom' id='test' action='Returm URL' method='post'>
  <input  type='hidden' name='txtUserName' value='Process Completed Successfully'/>
<input  type='hidden' name='givenUserName' value='abc'/>
</form>


---Controller----

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> PostTodoItem()
{
    NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
    userName = nvc["givenUserName"];
    status = nvc["txtUserName"];
}
```

but i am getting 405 http error i need help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i am redirecting to page given below with query string format username|redirecturl

```
https://example.com/anonymouspage.aspx?req=username|https://localhost:5001/api/ControllerName/PostTodoItem
```

> above page will redirect back to controller url

If you do redirection via `HttpResponse.Redirect` Method in your `.aspx` code behind, it would make a `GET` request to your API action, but you applied `[HttpPost]` attribute to your API action, which cause the issue.

If you'd like to make a `POST` request to you API action `PostTodoItem`, you can refer to the following code snippet.

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    // in your code logic
    // you may need to generate following contnet 
    // based on the retrieved from data

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("givenUserName", "abc"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("txtUserName", "Process Completed Successfully")
    });

    var result = httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:5001/api/ControllerName/PostTodoItem", content).Result;

    //code logic here
    //...
```

Test Result

[image]